# Как задать высоту элемента исходя из текущей высоты фонового изображения

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день!

Необходимо, чтобы высота блока равнялась текущей высоте `background-size` данного блока

Подскажите реально ли вычислить текущую высоту `background-size` и задать ее для блока.

Максимальная высота блока = `452px`;

**[Вот код.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/aDxDK/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно реально.

Находите коэффициент отношения высоты к ширине (изображения), с помощью ширины блока находите высоту. У вас же, я так понял, изменяется ширина блока?

Comment: @lampa, спасибо! Спасибо, проблема решена. Дополнительный вопрос:

Как обновить js-файл при смене ориентации экрана?

Дело в том, что при смене ориентации на планшете, высота блока остается от предыдущей ориентации ...

Comment: @Astor зачем же файл обновлять? Или я вас не понял) В планшетных браузерах есть такой `event`, как `orientationchange`: 

        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", func, false);

Comment: @lampa, только-что проверял на планшете и проблема с высотой есть. Где прописывается данная строка? Или это должно "автоматом" работать?

Comment: @Astor так так, вижу непонимание :) строка добавляет событие на смену ориентации экрана планшета. Событие вызывает функцию `func`. Соответственно вы должны вместо этой функции подставить свою. Добавлять нужно с учетом других факторов: объявлена ли функция, в которой содержатся инструкции по изменению высоты. загружены ли элементы, с которых нужно получать данные. Ну как обычно.

Comment: @lampa, в который раз спасибо!

P.s: Роман, здорово было бы иметь такого наставника как Вы. Еще раз спасибо. Удачи.

Comment: @Astor спасибо, приятно) Буду иметь ввиду :)